# Unexpected Output Maybe Related to Data Type?

Tags: c, types

I am doing an exercise from a book to make a program that counts blanks tabs and newlines. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
        int blanks, tabs, newlines = 0;
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
                if (c ==' ')
                        ++blanks;
                if (c == '\t')
                        ++tabs;
                if (c == '\n')
                        ++newlines;
        printf("\n Blanks: %d. \n Tabs: %d. \n New lines: %d. \n", blanks, tabs, newlines);
}
```

The program seems to check the first if statement, sees that it's true, and goes back to the beginning of the while loop, why does this happen and what is the solution?

```
kingvon@KingVon:~/Desktop/C$ ./a.out
counts blanks
        but not tabs

or new lines

 Blanks: 5. 
 Tabs: 0. 
 New lines: 0.
```

Comment: Add `{` and `}` around the ifstatements in the while body. C syntax is not indentation dependent.

Comment: I bet you wrote Python before C.  In C, indentation never changes the meaning of the program. As @klutt said, you need to group statements with braces `{}`.

Comment: Wow easy fix haha, previous sample codes from the book I was following was not using { } around the ifstatements, but also did not have multiple ifstatements. Would you explain more about this? And also any adjusetments/improvements you would make to the code?

Comment: @raincouver Google "C scope" and you'll find what you need. Multistatement scopes requires braces and you have three if statements that should be in one scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the {} to  the while loop . if you use the loop without {} , it loop the First line after it only , but when you use {} it loop all the code  between the {} .

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
                if (c ==' ')
                        ++blanks;
                if (c == '\t')
                        ++tabs;
                if (c == '\n')
                        ++newlines;
};
```